# html dropdown with SandBoxMode.IFRAME

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a piece of code (sorry lost the link to original) but I am struggling and cannot get past the error message "The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type". I have looked at changing this to a string, but to be honest I am at the limit of my ability to understand what I am trying to do. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

code.gs is:

```
function getMenu1() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myForm');
  t.data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('11_3xQkJdQ172_97LWUoOu22qUMBS-vSrr7TN9bqWicg')
      .getSheetByName('PROJECTS')
      .getRange('D:D')
      .getValues();
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  Logger.log('doGetMenu1 ran');
}
```

and myform.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">

      <div>
        <input class="left" type="text" name="cuStaff" id="cuStaff" style="width=150px" required>
          <datalist id="cuStaff">
          </datalist>

        <input class="left" type="date" name="dateA" id="dateA" style="width:150px" required>
        <input class="left" type="time" name="timeA" id="timeA" style="width:75px" required>

      </div>



    </body>

<select id="cuStaff">
  <option> Choose a option </option>
</select >

<body onload = "addList()"></body>

<script>
  function addList() {
    console.log('addList ran!');

    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .withSuccessHandler(injectMyContent)
      .getMenu1();
  };

  window.injectMyContent = function(argReturnedData) {
    for(var i = 0; i < argReturnedData.length; i++) {
      var opt = argReturnedData[i];
      var document = myForm.html
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      var el = document
      el.text = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
    };
  };

  window.onFailure = function(err) {
    alert('There was an error! ' + err.message);
  };

</script >

  </head>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/witham/akea7ajr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the 2 functions are being mixed. Try:

```js
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myForm');
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function getMenu1() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('11_3xQkJdQ172_97LWUoOu22qUMBS-vSrr7TN9bqWicg')
      .getSheetByName('PROJECTS')
      .getRange('D:D')
      .getValues();
  Logger.log('getMenu1 ran')
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Bryan P. That is doing something as the console is showing the navigation to the script and the logger is capturing the 'getMenu1 ran' but it is now saying the ' "data"is not defined'

Comment: Sorry Bryan P, I had a typo. That is pulling the data from the spreadsheet and showing it in the log. It isn't pushing it to. The client side drop down but I'll work on that and see if I can crack it.

Comment: try changing `window.injectMyContent = function` to just `function injectMyContent`